# Maximal munch in Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP

Tags: parsing, haskell

The Read instance for Double behaves in a very straightforward way:

```
reads "34.567e8 foo" :: [(Double, String)] = [(3.4567e9," foo")]
```

However the Read instance for [Scientific](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/scientific-0.2.0.2/docs/Data-Scientific.html) does something different:

```
reads "34.567e8 foo" :: [(Scientific, String)] = 
   [(34.0,".567e8 foo"),(34.567,"e8 foo"),(3.4567e9," foo")]
```

Strictly this is correct, in that it is presenting a list of possible parses of the input. In fact it could equally well have included (3.0, "4.567e8 foo") in the list, as well as some others. However the usual behaviour in cases like this (which the Double instance follows) is "[maximal munch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_munch)", meaning that the longest valid prefix is parsed.

I'm updating my [Decimal](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Decimal-0.3.1/docs/Data-Decimal.html) library, which has a similar behaviour, and I'm wondering what the Right Thing is here. Both Scientific and Decimal are using Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP, which was designed to make it easy to write Read instances, and this seems to be a characteristic of ReadP parsers.

So my questions:

1: What is the Right Thing for "reads" to return in these cases? Should I file a bug for Data.Scientific?

2: If it should only return the maximal munch (like the Double instance does) then how do you get ReadP to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've decided that maximal munch is the Right Thing. Given "1.23" a parser that returns 1 is just wrong. I've been tripped up by this myself because I once tried to write a "maybeRead" looking like this:

```
maybeRead :: (Read a) => String -> Maybe a
maybeRead str = case reads str of
   [v, ""] -> Just v
   _ => Nothing
```

This worked fine for Double but failed for Decimal and Scientific. (Obviously it can be fixed to handle multiple return results, but I didn't expect to need to do this).

The problem turned out to be the implementation of "optional" in Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP. This uses the symmetric choice operator "+++", which returns the parse with and without the optional component.  Hence when I wrote something like

```
expPart <- optional "" $ do {...}
```

the results included a parse without the expPart.

I wrote a different version of "optional" using the left-biased choice operator:

```
 myOpt d p = p <++ return d
```

If the parser "p" consumes any text then the default is not used. This does the Right Thing if you want maximal munch.

Answer (score 0):

For #2, you could change the scientific package to use this parser defined in terms of the old one: `scientificPmaxmuch = scientificP <* eof :: ReadP Scientific`.

I don't think there is much of a convention for #1: it doesn't make a difference for people using `read` or `Text.Read.readMaybe`. `readS_to_P reads :: ReadP Double` is probably faster than `readS_to_P reads :: ReadP Scientific`, but if efficiency mattered at all you would keep everything as `ReadP` until the end.

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work with reads "34.567e8 foo" because it wants to see the end of text. The Right Thing in the above is [(3.4567e9, " foo")]